# Close/open the PDFviewer automatically while compiling

Tags: viewers, winedt

I am using **WinEdt 7.0** and my default **pdf viewer** is **FoxitReader**. So when I press **F9** (compile) in WinEdt, it compiles and shows the **pdf** automatically. I want to set **WinEdt** somehow that after some editing of the **tex** file, when I want to compile and view the **pdf** I just press the **F9** and the editor automatically closes the previous **pdf** and shows the updated **pdf** afterwards.

If I try to recompile the file while the viewer is open the output would be:

```
I can't write on file 'filename.pdf'
please type another file name for output:
```

Simply I want to open/close the **pdf viewer** automatically from **WinEdt**. I think there is a script (something like that) for that (e.g. `--single-instance` but I couldn't get it to work).

Comment: What happens if you compile the `tex` file with the `pdf` file opened? Is not enough just use `Alt+Tab` to call the viewer with updated file?

Comment: What don't you use SumatraPDF which doesn't lock your pdf file and lets you do direct and inverse search? It doesn't require to be the default pdf viewer in order to use it with WinEdt.

Comment: Foxit can not be controlled by DDE, so WinEdt is not able to close it before compiling. I suggest you to follow @Bernard's suggestion.

Comment: @karlkoeller Please write an answer to remove this question from the unanswered list.

Comment: @Arzigoglu An answer by the OP is already there...

Comment: @karlkoeller It has appeared after I posted my comment...

Comment: Other possible causes for the error message: [Other causes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78362),
[Adobe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288470),
[Foxit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152911),
[Avast](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553773).

Answer (score 2):

I have to mention that so far there is no solution for conventional PDF viewers such as `Adobe Acrobat Reader` and `Foxit Reader`. However, as @Bernard mentioned, by installing `SumatraPDF` and setting the PDF viewer setting in the `WinEdt`:

```
Execution Modes > PDF Viewer > "C:\Users\NKN\Documents\SumatraPDF-3.1.1\SumatraPDF.exe"
```

now the system reopens and updates the PDF even if it was already open.

As a final point, although this question was posted in 2014, the problem still remains (in 2017) even with newer versions of **WinEdt (9.1/10)**, `Foxit Reader`, and `Adobe Reader`.

Comment: Evince is also an option though the windows build is way out of date.  What's really annoying is that foxit didn't block the pdf file from being overwritten, until some time in about 2012/2013 when it started to.  I got in touch with them when the change happened, and got a pleasant enough but unhelpful reply

Comment: @ChrisH Evince cannot be controlled through DDE, so I don't think it's a good option for working with WinEdt.

Comment: Adobe Reader supports DDE so it can be controlled by WinEdt, although it doesn't support forward/inverse search. Foxit is not controllable at all...

Comment: @karlkoeller, my point was that by not blocking the file, and automatically refreshing (while staying on the same page), it allows you to overwrite the pdf without closing and reopening. In that respect it's like sumatra. DDE is a red herring as regards what the OP was looking for (stopping the "I can't write..." error) and only becomes relevant for searching

Comment: @ChrisH OK, got it.