# Can't write on file *.pdf

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I can no more compile any of my tex files, they all generate an error "can't write on file *.pdf". I suspect a Windows update (it occurred just after that) but I am not sure and I cannot find any reason for that...

Even the simple "hello world" does not work and generates the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

I am using Windows 10 and Texmaker. I know that Adobe can lead to this error but the PDF is neither open, nor created on my computer.

So, the file is not open, I have reinstalled both Miktex & Texmaker, I am not using Dropbox & co, I tested with other editors leading to the same result, searched on google for hours, restarted my computer many times, I have enough space on my computer.

But I am now lacking solutions... Does anyone have a suggestion ?

Comment: the last two who had this error had a problem with a virus program kicking in (Avast in both cases). See e.g. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/585

Comment: Many thanks ! That was indeed Avast... Maybe an update which did wrong. What I did: uninstall Avast, then click on "repair", and it fixes the problem (Avast asked the permission for executing pdflatex).
Thanks Ulrike Fischer!

Comment: No need to install `Avast` on `Windows` since the native antivirus of `Windows defender` is also if not more powerful, see :   [The best Windows antivirus software for home users](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/)

Comment: Other possible causes for the error message: [Other causes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78362),
[Adobe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288470),
[Foxit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152911),
[Avast](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553773).

Answer (score 11):

The last two who had this error had a problem with a virus program kicking in
(Avast in both cases).

See e.g. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/585