# "I can't write on file" error occurs in every folder except Google Drive

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, folders

I am using MiKTeX on Windows 10 with TeXStudio and I am literally trying to compile the simplest TeX document possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

And I get the following error:

> ! I can't write on
> file `proof.pdf'.

No such file exists yet, so that's not the common issue of having the file open on Acrobat Reader. Here is my version information:

```
C:\Users\amitt>pdflatex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.1 (MiKTeX 20.12)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2020 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
compiled with curl version 7.72.0; using libcurl/7.72.0 Schannel
compiled with expat version 2.2.10; using expat_2.2.10
compiled with jpeg version 9.4
compiled with liblzma version 50020052; using 50020052
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 3.1.4; using LibreSSL 3.1.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.3; using 4.3
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.1; using 4.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.4
compiled with xpdf version 4.02
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

And here is the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.12.22)  22 DEC 2020 11:46
entering extended mode
**./proof.tex
(proof.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\c@figure=\count183
\c@table=\count184
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count185
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (proof.aux)
\openout1 = `proof.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

! I can't write on file `proof.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  
l.5 \end{document}
                  
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 382 strings out of 479696
 6840 string characters out of 2876950
 271423 words of memory out of 3000000
 17563 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 43i,4n,49p,129b,100s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Oddly enough, this issue *does not* occur when I try compiling a TeX file found on my Google Drive sync folder - but it *does* seem to occur on any other folder. I do not know when this started happening, since I normally work on my Google Drive folder.

Comment: do you have any virus protection or similar?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: I am using Avast Free AntiVirus. My PDF viewer is Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: File may be locked by reader, which show result of the previous compilation. Close Reader before compilation.

Comment: @Zarko Reader is closed, and there is no previous compilation. The file 'proof.pdf' does not exist.

Comment: Your example works. Compiled with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX ... so, your file is locked with some other program, which use it. Just rename it and than see, what happens. It also may help to erase `.sytex` and `.log` file. Or simply, restart your computer.

Comment: Maybe your user-ID isn't allowed to write a PDF at all. Open a cmd.exe and navigate to the folder of the TeX-file. In the cmd-window type `touch proof.pdf`. A second later in the explorer windows in that folder there should be a file proof.pdf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't write on file \*.pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553773/cant-write-on-file-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It was the Avast AntiVirus. I had to approve pdflatex to let it know this program is allowed to make changes to files and folders.