# XeLaTeX Can't Write to File

Tags: xetex, filesystem-access

Occasionally, when running `xelatex` (using TeX Live 2018 on Linux Mint 19.2), I
encounter the following error message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def) [1
! I can't write on file `xxx.pdf'.
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.pdf')
Please type another file name for output:
```

This happened to me yesterday evening, and I found myself expending an hour of my time trying to nail down
what could be causing causing such a behavior.

I had a document viewer with the PDF open so naturally that could have been blocking access to the file so I
closed the program, but to no avail (I'm using Evince which is most of the time fine, does automatically
reload on document update, but has also occasionally been known to become unresponsive for no tractable
reason).

I tried then to remove all temporary files and the PDF from the target folder; in my case this included all
files matching `*.aux`, `*.fls`, `*.log`, `*.out`, and `*.pdf`; this had no discernible effect.

I also tried to write to another target:

```
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.pdf')
Please type another file name for output: /tmp/x.pdf
! I can't write on file `/tmp/x.pdf'.
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.pdf')
```

This did not spark joy.

During my continued efforts to come to grips with this I could produce a PDF roughly one out of two or three
runs; I was unable to make the behavior predictable—it's not the viewer, it's none of the existing files in
the directory, all packages that are loaded are always the exact same ones.

Has there been any experience as to possible reasons for failure to write to the target or any other file?
If the specific target had been blocked, then surely entering a non-existing filename in the existing `/tmp`
directory should *always* work, right? It feels as if the 'file writing mechanism' of TeX has a washer
hopping around in the gear, sometimes causing it to grind to a halt.

I will say that this work is being done on a recent but not terribly performant netbook, IOW it might be the
case that shortage of RAM is the underlying problem and failure to write just the visible side effect of
that. Maybe someone can corroborate or refute that; personally I would of course prefer any software to fail
with an Out of Memory error when that is indeed the problem.

Comment: this is almost certainly an operating system lock, so it's either the file permissions or a (possibly zombie) process is holding the file, hard to diagnose remotely:-)

Comment: with xetex it is xdvipdfmx rather than xetex that writes the pdf  so it's possible that in some run xdvipdfmx didn't quit cleanly and is hanging around in the background which could block a second run on the same file.

Comment: Your theory about low RAM might actually be correct: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16801/xelatex-i-cant-write-on-file-test-pdf?rq=1

Comment: Somehow my earlier comment disappeared... @DavidCarlisle I could rule out the possibility of it being a lock, it would otherwise be the most likely cause.

Comment: @DisenchantedLurker would you mind making an answer out of your comment so I can go and accept it?

Comment: @JohnFrazer If it is really the same issue, it would be better to close this question as a duplicate of the other one. Otherwise I'd just be repeating what's written there, and that's frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problems for this kind of mistake can have varied origins.

Below you can find links to a couple of threads that talk about a similar problem to yours:

- [I can't write on file 'Filename.pdf'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240860/i-cant-write-on-file-filename-pdf/240956)
- [Fatal error, "Can't write on file 'test.pdf'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170721/fatal-error-cant-write-on-file-test-pdf)

I hope you can use them.

Comment: Thanks for the links but none of the hints apply to my case; I guess it's an out of memory error